# Can you add multiple values to one key in an Elixir map?

Tags: elixir

I have a map of key value pairs that pair a specific type of drone with the type of photoshoot. Here is an example:
    `%{ :real_estate => "Normal", :nature => "FPV", :wedding  => "Cinewhoop" }`

However, for the :nature scenario, I also would like to use the "Normal" drone in addition to the "FPV" option. In other words, given :nature, I want to return "Normal" and "FPV".

Is there a way to add multiple values to a key value pair? Or is there a different Elixir method that would suit this problem better?

I looked through the docs and didn't find an option to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Maps in Elixir don't allow duplicate keys. Values in maps can also be lists (or any term), so you can always replace the value in the pair with a list of values if that matches your use case:

```
%{real_estate: "Normal", nature: ["Normal", "FPV"], wedding: "Cinewhoop"}
```

Lists of key-value pairs, such as [keyword lists](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Keyword.html), do allow for duplicate keys:

```
[real_estate: "Normal", nature: "FPV", wedding: "Cinewhoop", nature: "Normal"]
```

In the end, though, how you choose to represent your data really comes down to how you intend to use it.

Comment: Thank you! Using a list inside the map makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Or to give you an answer using the same syntax as your original example, this would work:

```
%{ :real_estate => "Normal", :nature => ["Normal","FPV"], :wedding  => "Cinewhoop" }
```

Simply use a list for the value rather than a single string.